# Symfony 4 как добавить класс родителю в котором лежит input

Tags: symfony4, symfony-form

Я использую для разметки bootstrap 4 и хочу добавить родителю в котором лежит input класс form-group, как можно это сделать?

ArticleController.php

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($article)
            ->add('title', TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
            ->add('body', TextareaType::class, array(
                'required' => false,
                'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')
            ))
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Create',
                'attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-primary mt-3')
            ))->getForm();
```

article/index.html

```
<div class="container">
        {{ form_start(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        {{ form_end(form) }}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

добавить аттрибут class в шаблоне

```
<div class="container">
        {{ form_start(form) }}
        <div class="form-group"> 
         {{ form_widget(form.title) }}
        </div>
         <div class="form-group"> 
         {{ form_widget(form.body) }}
        </div>
         {{ form_widget(form.save) }}
        {{ form_end(form) }}
    </div>
```

Comment: если {{ form_start(form), {'attr': {'class': 'form-group'}} }} так сделать то на тег <form> добавиться класс form-group а не на div в котором Input

Comment: Изменил ответ. Можете попробовать. Под рукой симфони нет, так что идем по приборам ))

Comment: да, такой способ работает, я думал чтото возможно в ArticleController.php это сделать